# printf wrong on floating point

Tags: c

I definitely cant figure it out. Printing `sum` gives a wrong value. If the comment on in-the-loop `printf` is removed everything works as expected. If `const float values[]` is declared inside the `main` body, `printf` again behaves normally. Why is this happening?

```
/* blah */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <float.h>

/* declare 1000 elements array*/
const float values[] = {
    1.000000F, 1.259921F, 1.442250F, 1.587401F, 1.709976F, 1.817121F, 
    1.912931F, 2.000000F, 2.080084F, 2.154435F, 2.223980F, 2.289428F, 
    2.351335F, 2.410142F, 2.466212F, 2.519842F, 2.571282F, 2.620741F, 
    2.668402F, 2.714418F, 2.758924F, 2.802039F, 2.843867F, 2.884499F, 
    2.924018F, 2.962496F, 3.000000F, 3.036589F, 3.072317F, 3.107233F, 
    3.141381F, 3.174802F, 3.207534F, 3.239612F, 3.271066F, 3.301927F, 
    3.332222F, 3.361975F, 3.391211F, 3.419952F, 3.448217F, 3.476027F, 
    3.503398F, 3.530348F, 3.556893F, 3.583048F, 3.608826F, 3.634241F, 
    3.659306F, 3.684031F, 3.708430F, 3.732511F, 3.756286F, 3.779763F, 
    3.802953F, 3.825862F, 3.848501F, 3.870877F, 3.892997F, 3.914868F, 
    3.936497F, 3.957892F, 3.979057F, 4.000000F, 4.020726F, 4.041240F, 
    4.061548F, 4.081655F, 4.101566F, 4.121285F, 4.140818F, 4.160168F, 
    4.179339F, 4.198337F, 4.217164F, 4.235824F, 4.254321F, 4.272659F, 
    4.290840F, 4.308869F, 4.326749F, 4.344481F, 4.362071F, 4.379519F, 
    4.396830F, 4.414005F, 4.431048F, 4.447960F, 4.464745F, 4.481405F, 
    4.497941F, 4.514358F, 4.530655F, 4.546836F, 4.562902F, 4.578857F, 
    4.594701F, 4.610436F, 4.626065F, 4.641589F, 4.657010F, 4.672329F, 
    4.687548F, 4.702669F, 4.717694F, 4.732624F, 4.747459F, 4.762203F, 
    4.776856F, 4.791420F, 4.805895F, 4.820284F, 4.834588F, 4.848808F, 
    4.862944F, 4.876999F, 4.890973F, 4.904868F, 4.918684F, 4.932424F, 
    4.946087F, 4.959676F, 4.973190F, 4.986631F, 5.000000F, 5.013298F, 
    5.026525F, 5.039684F, 5.052774F, 5.065797F, 5.078753F, 5.091643F, 
    5.104469F, 5.117230F, 5.129928F, 5.142563F, 5.155137F, 5.167649F, 
    5.180101F, 5.192494F, 5.204828F, 5.217103F, 5.229321F, 5.241483F, 
    5.253588F, 5.265637F, 5.277632F, 5.289572F, 5.301459F, 5.313293F, 
    5.325074F, 5.336803F, 5.348481F, 5.360108F, 5.371686F, 5.383213F, 
    5.394691F, 5.406120F, 5.417501F, 5.428835F, 5.440122F, 5.451362F, 
    5.462555F, 5.473704F, 5.484807F, 5.495864F, 5.506878F, 5.517848F, 
    5.528775F, 5.539658F, 5.550499F, 5.561298F, 5.572055F, 5.582770F, 
    5.593445F, 5.604079F, 5.614672F, 5.625226F, 5.635741F, 5.646216F, 
    5.656653F, 5.667051F, 5.677411F, 5.687734F, 5.698020F, 5.708268F, 
    5.718479F, 5.728654F, 5.738793F, 5.748897F, 5.758965F, 5.768998F, 
    5.778996F, 5.788960F, 5.798890F, 5.808786F, 5.818648F, 5.828476F, 
    5.838273F, 5.848035F, 5.857766F, 5.867464F, 5.877131F, 5.886765F, 
    5.896369F, 5.905941F, 5.915482F, 5.924992F, 5.934472F, 5.943922F, 
    5.953342F, 5.962732F, 5.972093F, 5.981424F, 5.990726F, 6.000000F, 
    6.009245F, 6.018462F, 6.027650F, 6.036811F, 6.045944F, 6.055049F, 
    6.064127F, 6.073178F, 6.082202F, 6.091199F, 6.100170F, 6.109115F, 
    6.118033F, 6.126926F, 6.135792F, 6.144634F, 6.153450F, 6.162240F, 
    6.171006F, 6.179747F, 6.188463F, 6.197155F, 6.205822F, 6.214465F, 
    6.223084F, 6.231680F, 6.240252F, 6.248800F, 6.257325F, 6.265827F, 
    6.274305F, 6.282762F, 6.291194F, 6.299605F, 6.307993F, 6.316360F, 
    6.324704F, 6.333025F, 6.341326F, 6.349604F, 6.357861F, 6.366097F, 
    6.374311F, 6.382504F, 6.390676F, 6.398828F, 6.406959F, 6.415069F, 
    6.423158F, 6.431228F, 6.439277F, 6.447306F, 6.455315F, 6.463304F, 
    6.471273F, 6.479224F, 6.487154F, 6.495065F, 6.502957F, 6.510830F, 
    6.518684F, 6.526519F, 6.534335F, 6.542133F, 6.549911F, 6.557672F, 
    6.565414F, 6.573139F, 6.580844F, 6.588532F, 6.596202F, 6.603855F, 
    6.611489F, 6.619106F, 6.626706F, 6.634287F, 6.641852F, 6.649400F, 
    6.656930F, 6.664443F, 6.671940F, 6.679420F, 6.686883F, 6.694330F, 
    6.701759F, 6.709173F, 6.716570F, 6.723951F, 6.731316F, 6.738664F, 
    6.745996F, 6.753314F, 6.760614F, 6.767900F, 6.775169F, 6.782423F, 
    6.789661F, 6.796884F, 6.804092F, 6.811285F, 6.818462F, 6.825624F, 
    6.832771F, 6.839904F, 6.847021F, 6.854124F, 6.861212F, 6.868285F, 
    6.875344F, 6.882389F, 6.889419F, 6.896435F, 6.903436F, 6.910423F, 
    6.917397F, 6.924356F, 6.931301F, 6.938232F, 6.945149F, 6.952053F, 
    6.958943F, 6.965820F, 6.972682F, 6.979532F, 6.986368F, 6.993191F, 
    7.000000F, 7.006796F, 7.013579F, 7.020349F, 7.027106F, 7.033850F, 
    7.040581F, 7.047298F, 7.054004F, 7.060697F, 7.067377F, 7.074044F, 
    7.080698F, 7.087341F, 7.093971F, 7.100588F, 7.107193F, 7.113787F, 
    7.120368F, 7.126936F, 7.133492F, 7.140037F, 7.146570F, 7.153090F, 
    7.159599F, 7.166096F, 7.172581F, 7.179055F, 7.185516F, 7.191967F, 
    7.198405F, 7.204832F, 7.211248F, 7.217652F, 7.224045F, 7.230427F, 
    7.236797F, 7.243156F, 7.249505F, 7.255841F, 7.262167F, 7.268482F, 
    7.274786F, 7.281080F, 7.287362F, 7.293633F, 7.299894F, 7.306144F, 
    7.312383F, 7.318612F, 7.324830F, 7.331037F, 7.337234F, 7.343421F, 
    7.349597F, 7.355762F, 7.361917F, 7.368063F, 7.374198F, 7.380323F, 
    7.386437F, 7.392542F, 7.398636F, 7.404721F, 7.410795F, 7.416860F, 
    7.422914F, 7.428959F, 7.434994F, 7.441019F, 7.447034F, 7.453040F, 
    7.459036F, 7.465022F, 7.470999F, 7.476966F, 7.482924F, 7.488873F, 
    7.494811F, 7.500741F, 7.506661F, 7.512571F, 7.518473F, 7.524365F, 
    7.530248F, 7.536122F, 7.541987F, 7.547843F, 7.553689F, 7.559526F, 
    7.565355F, 7.571174F, 7.576985F, 7.582787F, 7.588579F, 7.594363F, 
    7.600139F, 7.605905F, 7.611663F, 7.617412F, 7.623152F, 7.628884F, 
    7.634607F, 7.640321F, 7.646027F, 7.651725F, 7.657414F, 7.663095F, 
    7.668766F, 7.674430F, 7.680086F, 7.685733F, 7.691372F, 7.697002F, 
    7.702625F, 7.708239F, 7.713845F, 7.719443F, 7.725032F, 7.730614F, 
    7.736187F, 7.741753F, 7.747311F, 7.752861F, 7.758402F, 7.763936F, 
    7.769462F, 7.774980F, 7.780490F, 7.785993F, 7.791488F, 7.796975F, 
    7.802454F, 7.807925F, 7.813389F, 7.818845F, 7.824294F, 7.829735F, 
    7.835169F, 7.840595F, 7.846013F, 7.851424F, 7.856828F, 7.862224F, 
    7.867613F, 7.872994F, 7.878368F, 7.883735F, 7.889094F, 7.894447F, 
    7.899792F, 7.905129F, 7.910460F, 7.915783F, 7.921099F, 7.926408F, 
    7.931710F, 7.937006F, 7.942293F, 7.947574F, 7.952847F, 7.958115F, 
    7.963374F, 7.968627F, 7.973873F, 7.979112F, 7.984344F, 7.989570F, 
    7.994788F, 8.000000F, 8.005205F, 8.010403F, 8.015594F, 8.020780F, 
    8.025957F, 8.031129F, 8.036293F, 8.041451F, 8.046603F, 8.051748F, 
    8.056887F, 8.062018F, 8.067143F, 8.072262F, 8.077374F, 8.082480F, 
    8.087580F, 8.092672F, 8.097759F, 8.102839F, 8.107913F, 8.112981F, 
    8.118042F, 8.123096F, 8.128145F, 8.133187F, 8.138223F, 8.143252F, 
    8.148276F, 8.153294F, 8.158305F, 8.163310F, 8.168309F, 8.173302F, 
    8.178288F, 8.183270F, 8.188244F, 8.193213F, 8.198175F, 8.203132F, 
    8.208082F, 8.213027F, 8.217966F, 8.222898F, 8.227825F, 8.232746F, 
    8.237661F, 8.242571F, 8.247474F, 8.252372F, 8.257263F, 8.262149F, 
    8.267030F, 8.271904F, 8.276772F, 8.281635F, 8.286492F, 8.291345F, 
    8.296190F, 8.301030F, 8.305865F, 8.310694F, 8.315517F, 8.320335F, 
    8.325148F, 8.329954F, 8.334755F, 8.339551F, 8.344341F, 8.349126F, 
    8.353905F, 8.358678F, 8.363446F, 8.368210F, 8.372967F, 8.377719F, 
    8.382465F, 8.387206F, 8.391942F, 8.396673F, 8.401399F, 8.406118F, 
    8.410832F, 8.415542F, 8.420246F, 8.424945F, 8.429638F, 8.434327F, 
    8.439010F, 8.443687F, 8.448360F, 8.453028F, 8.457690F, 8.462348F, 
    8.467000F, 8.471647F, 8.476289F, 8.480927F, 8.485559F, 8.490185F, 
    8.494806F, 8.499423F, 8.504035F, 8.508642F, 8.513244F, 8.517840F, 
    8.522432F, 8.527019F, 8.531601F, 8.536178F, 8.540750F, 8.545318F, 
    8.549880F, 8.554437F, 8.558990F, 8.563538F, 8.568081F, 8.572618F, 
    8.577152F, 8.581680F, 8.586205F, 8.590724F, 8.595238F, 8.599748F, 
    8.604252F, 8.608752F, 8.613248F, 8.617739F, 8.622225F, 8.626706F, 
    8.631183F, 8.635654F, 8.640122F, 8.644586F, 8.649044F, 8.653498F, 
    8.657947F, 8.662391F, 8.666831F, 8.671267F, 8.675697F, 8.680123F, 
    8.684546F, 8.688963F, 8.693376F, 8.697784F, 8.702188F, 8.706588F, 
    8.710982F, 8.715373F, 8.719760F, 8.724141F, 8.728518F, 8.732891F, 
    8.737260F, 8.741625F, 8.745985F, 8.750340F, 8.754691F, 8.759038F, 
    8.763381F, 8.767719F, 8.772053F, 8.776383F, 8.780708F, 8.785029F, 
    8.789347F, 8.793659F, 8.797968F, 8.802272F, 8.806572F, 8.810868F, 
    8.815160F, 8.819448F, 8.823730F, 8.828011F, 8.832285F, 8.836555F, 
    8.840822F, 8.845085F, 8.849344F, 8.853599F, 8.857849F, 8.862096F, 
    8.866338F, 8.870576F, 8.874810F, 8.879040F, 8.883266F, 8.887488F, 
    8.891706F, 8.895921F, 8.900130F, 8.904337F, 8.908539F, 8.912737F, 
    8.916931F, 8.921122F, 8.925307F, 8.929490F, 8.933668F, 8.937843F, 
    8.942014F, 8.946180F, 8.950344F, 8.954503F, 8.958658F, 8.962810F, 
    8.966957F, 8.971101F, 8.975241F, 8.979377F, 8.983509F, 8.987638F, 
    8.991762F, 8.995883F, 9.000000F, 9.004113F, 9.008223F, 9.012329F, 
    9.016431F, 9.020529F, 9.024624F, 9.028715F, 9.032803F, 9.036886F, 
    9.040966F, 9.045042F, 9.049114F, 9.053183F, 9.057248F, 9.061310F, 
    9.065368F, 9.069422F, 9.073473F, 9.077519F, 9.081563F, 9.085603F, 
    9.089639F, 9.093672F, 9.097701F, 9.101727F, 9.105748F, 9.109767F, 
    9.113782F, 9.117793F, 9.121801F, 9.125805F, 9.129807F, 9.133803F, 
    9.137797F, 9.141788F, 9.145775F, 9.149757F, 9.153737F, 9.157714F, 
    9.161687F, 9.165657F, 9.169622F, 9.173585F, 9.177545F, 9.181500F, 
    9.185452F, 9.189402F, 9.193348F, 9.197289F, 9.201228F, 9.205164F, 
    9.209096F, 9.213025F, 9.216950F, 9.220873F, 9.224792F, 9.228706F, 
    9.232618F, 9.236527F, 9.240434F, 9.244335F, 9.248235F, 9.252130F, 
    9.256022F, 9.259912F, 9.263797F, 9.267680F, 9.271559F, 9.275435F, 
    9.279308F, 9.283177F, 9.287045F, 9.290907F, 9.294767F, 9.298624F, 
    9.302478F, 9.306328F, 9.310175F, 9.314019F, 9.317860F, 9.321697F, 
    9.325532F, 9.329364F, 9.333192F, 9.337017F, 9.340838F, 9.344658F, 
    9.348474F, 9.352285F, 9.356095F, 9.359901F, 9.363705F, 9.367505F, 
    9.371303F, 9.375096F, 9.378887F, 9.382675F, 9.386460F, 9.390242F, 
    9.394021F, 9.397797F, 9.401569F, 9.405338F, 9.409105F, 9.412869F, 
    9.416630F, 9.420387F, 9.424142F, 9.427894F, 9.431643F, 9.435388F, 
    9.439131F, 9.442870F, 9.446608F, 9.450341F, 9.454072F, 9.457800F, 
    9.461525F, 9.465247F, 9.468966F, 9.472682F, 9.476396F, 9.480106F, 
    9.483813F, 9.487518F, 9.491220F, 9.494919F, 9.498615F, 9.502308F, 
    9.505998F, 9.509686F, 9.513370F, 9.517052F, 9.520730F, 9.524406F, 
    9.528079F, 9.531750F, 9.535418F, 9.539082F, 9.542744F, 9.546403F, 
    9.550058F, 9.553712F, 9.557364F, 9.561010F, 9.564656F, 9.568298F, 
    9.571938F, 9.575575F, 9.579208F, 9.582840F, 9.586468F, 9.590094F, 
    9.593717F, 9.597338F, 9.600955F, 9.604569F, 9.608182F, 9.611791F, 
    9.615397F, 9.619001F, 9.622602F, 9.626202F, 9.629798F, 9.633390F, 
    9.636981F, 9.640569F, 9.644155F, 9.647737F, 9.651317F, 9.654894F, 
    9.658468F, 9.662040F, 9.665609F, 9.669176F, 9.672740F, 9.676302F, 
    9.679860F, 9.683416F, 9.686971F, 9.690521F, 9.694070F, 9.697616F, 
    9.701159F, 9.704699F, 9.708237F, 9.711772F, 9.715305F, 9.718835F, 
    9.722363F, 9.725888F, 9.729411F, 9.732931F, 9.736448F, 9.739964F, 
    9.743476F, 9.746985F, 9.750493F, 9.753998F, 9.757501F, 9.761000F, 
    9.764498F, 9.767992F, 9.771484F, 9.774974F, 9.778461F, 9.781946F, 
    9.785429F, 9.788909F, 9.792386F, 9.795861F, 9.799334F, 9.802804F, 
    9.806272F, 9.809736F, 9.813199F, 9.816659F, 9.820117F, 9.823572F, 
    9.827025F, 9.830476F, 9.833924F, 9.837369F, 9.840813F, 9.844254F, 
    9.847692F, 9.851128F, 9.854562F, 9.857993F, 9.861422F, 9.864848F, 
    9.868272F, 9.871695F, 9.875113F, 9.878531F, 9.881945F, 9.885357F, 
    9.888767F, 9.892175F, 9.895580F, 9.898983F, 9.902384F, 9.905782F, 
    9.909178F, 9.912571F, 9.915962F, 9.919352F, 9.922738F, 9.926123F, 
    9.929504F, 9.932884F, 9.936261F, 9.939636F, 9.943009F, 9.946380F, 
    9.949748F, 9.953114F, 9.956477F, 9.959839F, 9.963198F, 9.966555F, 
    9.969910F, 9.973262F, 9.976612F, 9.979959F, 9.983305F, 9.986649F, 
    9.989990F, 9.993329F, 9.996666F };

int main (void)
{

    float sum = 0.0F;
    int r;
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        r = rand()%1000;
        sum += values[r];
        //printf("%f, %f, %d\n",sum, values[r], r);
    }
    printf("bytes: %ld\n", sizeof(sum));
    printf("Floatmax: %f\n", FLT_MAX);
    printf("Result: %f\n", sum);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using a random index for an array of 1000 items, but `values` doesn't have 1000 items.

Comment: You're summing random elements, how do you know what the expected result is?

Comment: The array `values` consists of 999 elements, so valid indexes are from `0` to `998`. You are probably reading from the array out of bounds.

Comment: `"Printing sum gives a wrong value"` -- This statement is not very useful. Please specify the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Re “works as expected”: You have not said what you expect, so we do not know what you think might be wrong. Similarly, “gives a wrong value” is not helpful. Show the output you observe in the case you think is incorrect, the output you observe in the case you think is working, and explain why you think one is correct and the other is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the interesting hints and sorry for being unclear.
@Barman, Spot on. that out of one led `printf` to output `Result: 732298034581382536831696896.000000`, which was clearly wrong. Fun fact, moving the declaration of `values` inside main body got a `Result: 73102904.000000` closer to `73194824.000000` which is (in my own pseudo random generated sequence) the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Add     `srand(time(NULL));` before the loop.

Then every time you run the program `sum` will be different.

At the moment every time you run the program the "random" numbers sequence is exactly the same.

Also you access the array outside the bounds and it is undefined behaviour.

`r = rand()%(sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]));`

Comment: any comment silent DV-ter

Comment: Thanks, Pseudo random numbers are wanted. Being unaware of the boundary error I thought the issue was reproducible on every machine. I was clearly out of sight.

Answer (score -1):

You are using single precision floats, which use 32 bits of storage, with 23 bits for the non-sign/exponent bit. That means that two computations will be represented identically** if they differ by about 1 part in 10^6 or 10^7. Your numbers are all just on the edge of that, so you probably lose precision in your last digit or two. If this loss of accuracy is important in your application, use `double`s.

**rare cases of one rounding up and the other down aside.

Comment: The significand in the IEEE-754 binary32 format, commonly used for `float`, is 24 bits, not 23. 23 are encoded in the primary significand field, and 1 is encoded via the exponent field. All numbers within the normal exponent range converted to the nearest representable value in binary32 have a rounding error less than 1 part in 10^7 (at most 1 in 16,777,216). It is not correct to say numbers cannot be represented more accurately than that because infinitely many numbers can be represented more accurately than that, and some numbers can be represented exactly.

Comment: Nitpicking. (Thanks about the 24 though.) Question remains that the OP's numbers are on the edge and they will likely see inexact results.

Comment: The program adds 10 million single-precision numbers; the precision of each number is 24 bits, which as @eric says is a bit less than one part in ten million. The 10 million additions will erase practically all the precision. I tried this precise program (correcting the `%1000` to use the actual size of the array and using /dev/urandom to seed the PRNG); I summed the (same) values in a `double` accumulator and a `float` accumulator, and both sums were consistent. The `double` sums are 2.385% larger (2.374%-2.396% on 100 experiments).

Comment: As an additional data point, single-precision [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) produces virtually the same result as double precision summation; the difference is a few (single precision) ULPs.

Comment: This answer does not speak to the question asked, about the program behavior differing depending on whether the `printf` inside the loop is present or not.